# Set the return of a function to another module variable

Tags: vba, autocad

```
    '' Module1 Function    
    Public Function AddSelectionSet(ssName As String) As AcadSelectionSet
            On Error Resume Next
            Dim ss As AcadSelectionSet
            Set ss = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Add(ssName)
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Set ss = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Item(ssName)
            End If
        End Function

''Module2 code
Dim mySS As AcadSelectionSet
Set mySS = AddSelectionSet "myName"
```

Both above and below code results in "Syntax error" from AutoCAD's VBAIDE.

```
Set mySS = Call Module1.AddSelectionSet "myName"
```

Comment: Not an AutoCAD person, but try `Set mySS = AddSelectionSet("myName")`.

Comment: Your function never returns anything.... you need `Set AddSelectionSet = ss` so that it will return your `ss`, and your module2 code needs parenthesis around the `"myName"` part.

Comment: Thank you @braX and @BigBen! Added  `Set AddSelectionSet = ss` on Module1 and then: `Set mySS = AddSelectionSet("myName")`. on Module2, Works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function never returns anything....

You need `Set AddSelectionSet = ss` so that it will return your `ss`

```
Public Function AddSelectionSet(ssName As String) As AcadSelectionSet
  Dim ss As AcadSelectionSet

  On Error Resume Next
  Set ss = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Add(ssName)
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set ss = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Item(ssName)

  Set AddSelectionSet = ss
End Function
```

And then to use the function:

```
Dim mySS As AcadSelectionSet
Set mySS = AddSelectionSet("myName")
```